# az cli login with specific tenant generates error

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cloud-shell

I'm trying to login a different tenant from portal cloud shell bash with "az login --tenant mytenant.onmicrosoft.com" it gives error : azure cloud shell automatically authenticates the user it was initially launched under. As a result az login is disabled. How can I solve this problem any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> azure cloud shell automatically authenticates the user it was
>   initially launched under. As a result az login is disabled.

It is a by design behavior.

You could **switch** Azure AD in the upper right corner of Azure portal, then open cloud shell, in this way, Azure cloud shell will authenticates with that telnet.

Also you can download Azure CLI on your PC, more information about install CLI 2.0, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).

Comment: Does this work for you? please let me know if you need more help?

Comment: Does this helpful to you? if it helps, please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as an answer so that other community members will be benefited.